# How to use named graphs in a SPARQL Update against an in memory TripleStore with dotNetRDF

Tags: dotnetrdf

I've created a TripleStore and loaded several named graphs as part of an ETL job (the number of graphs can vary), but when I try to make `DELETE/INSERT` update operations and serialize the resulting dataset to N-Quads, then there are no changes made to the data. I want to enrich the data in the named graph(s) with additional statements that are inserted to the same named graph(s). Here follows an example procedure that should insert an extra statement for each triple matching the pattern `?s a ?o` into the same named graph:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
INSERT {
  GRAPH ?g {
    ?s a rdfs:Resource .
  }
}
WHERE {
  GRAPH ?g {
    ?s a ?o .
  }
}
```

I have read the [SPARQL Datasets](https://dotnetrdf.org/docs/stable/user_guide/sparql_datasets.html) page and it appears it may be necessary to use `USING NAMED` to specify the graphs over which the `WHERE` operates, but it is unclear why the dataset from the store is not used.

Is there any way to do this without enumerating each graph name in a `USING NAMED` clause? Otherwise, is it possible to use a SPARQL Parameterized String to mint such an update?

I ran the update procedure and no statements in the store were modified.

Comment: I did a quick test using an `InMemoryDataset` and your query behaves as expected (inserting the statements) with the default settings for the update processor. Can you share the code you are using to process the update and if you are using dotNetRDF to connect to a third-party store, what connector you are using for this.

Comment: It looks like we were adding statements into a graph like `graph.add(Triple(subject, predicate, object, graphURI))` which added the graph context when serializing out to N-Quads, but this was not recognized when running a query/update.

Adding the graph name as the BaseUri for the graph when adding it to the store solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The query looks perfectly good. Which repo gives you trouble?

If you need to use fixed graphs then:
`USING` only specifies where to get data from. `WITH` specifies also which graph to modify. See https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#deleteInsert